# HTML Purifier - How to know if a XSS injection was found?

Tags: php, xss, htmlpurifier

I'm using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to remove all malicious code from user input. I want to send an alert email when a XSS code is detected (and removed) by HTML Purifier.

The `purify()` method returns purified HTML. I can't compare the input HTML with the purified HTML to detect changes because HTML Purifier ensures standards-compliant output by transforming HTML.

Is it possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Found any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, HTML Purifier doesn't support this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a config setting that is maybe helpful in tracking the changes made by Purifier:

http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.CollectErrors

It says:

> Whether or not to collect errors found while filtering the document. This is a useful way to give feedback to your users.

But also (and this is the tricky part):

> **Warning**: Currently this feature is very patchy and experimental, with lots of possible error messages not yet implemented. It will not cause any problems, but it may not help your users either.

So I am not sure if this could be enough to know what errors (say XSS injection) are encountered by the Purifier.